# Deleting a bootstrap thumbnail with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have many thumbnails like the one pasted below on my page. What I am trying to do is to delete one of them using the delete button (`id=del`).

I tried using this code

```
$(this).parents('div');
```

but this code deletes all of them, which does make sense, because the thumbnails are in a div called `lblProducts`

I am new to jQuery and it is just not clear to me how to write my code so it picks exactly this thumbnail that I want to delete. The problem is that I am using the same pattern for all thumbnails and all elements have the same classes and id's, so I can't really use them for my filter.

```
 var sDivForProduct = '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"> \
                                    <div class="thumbnail"> \
                                      <img class="imgProduct" src="{{stock-icon}}" alt="idiot forgot icon"> \
                                      <div class="caption"> \
                                        <h3>{{stock-name}}</h3> \
                                        <p>{{stock-price}}</p> \
                                        <i class="fa {{validation-icon}} fa-1x"></i> \
                                        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-success" role="button">BUY</a> \
                                        <a href="#" id="del" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">DEL</a></p> \
                                      </div> \
                                    </div> \
                                  </div>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it: (This onclick method works for dynamic content)

```
$(document).on('click', 'div.thumbnail #del', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.imgProduct').remove();
});

// $(this)                DEL Button
// .parent()              P Tag
// .parent()              Div.caption
// .parent()              Div.thumbnail
// .find('.imgProduct')   Select Image
// .remove();             Remove it
```

---

Update: (Removing whole div)

```
$(document).on('click', 'div.thumbnail #del', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
});

// $(this)                DEL Button
// .parent()              P Tag
// .parent()              Div.caption
// .parent()              Div.thumbnail
// .parent()              Div.col-sm-6.col-md-3
// .remove();             Remove it
```

---

Update: (using .closest()) (credit to @gaetanoM)

Instead of the multiple .parent()s it may be better to use .closest();
As such the two versions would be:

```
// Version 1 (Just image)
$(this).closest('.thumbnail').find('.imgProduct').remove();

// Version 2 (Whole div)
$(this).closest('.col-sm-6.col-md-3').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It worked with some changes - $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();

Comment: Ah, yeah, I'd missed the <p> tag. And I thought you were only remove the image.

Comment: @user1866925 Edited the answer to help you further. If you could accept the answer that'd be awesome.